# Not getting coverage when testing async function that throws error

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I'm trying to write a unit test for the following method to check that it throws an error of type NotFoundException. The test passes as expected, but I'm not able to get any coverage of the lines within the catchError block. Line 13 and 14.

I'm wondering what I'm missing here?

Method being tested:

```
  async updateContact(
    contactId: number,
    authToken: string,
    data: Record<string, any>,
  ): Promise<Record<string, unknown>> {
    return this.httpService
      .put(`${this.config.customer.url}/contacts/${contactId}`, data, {
        headers: { Authorization: authToken },
      })
      .pipe(
        pluck('data'),
        catchError(err => {
          console.dir(err);
          throw err;
        }),
      )
      .toPromise();
  }
```

My test:

```
 const contactId = 1;
    const authToken = 'Bearer f4k3-70k3n';
    const data = { policy_id: 2 };

    it('should throw NotFoundException', async () => {
      jest.spyOn(sessionService, 'updateContact').mockRejectedValueOnce(new NotFoundException());
      await expect(sessionService.updateContact(contactId, authToken, data)).rejects.toThrowError(NotFoundException);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized the error....

I wrote a test that makes the updateContact method fail, which is why the test passes. But the catch block is connected to the httpService.put method, hence in order to be able to reach the lines within the catchError block, I need to make that method fail.

```
it('should throw http exception', async () => {
      jest.spyOn(httpService, 'put').mockReturnValueOnce(throwError(new NotFoundException()));
      await expect(sessionService.updateContact(contactId, authToken, data)).rejects.toThrowError(NotFoundException);
    });
```